# What theory discusses modes of "Being" vs. that of "Happening"?

Tags: psychoanalysis

Is there a theory (Perhaps Freudian) concerning that of "Being" and that of "Happening"? I vaguely recall learning about it many years ago in H.S. Psych, but of course any search for either of these keywords results in non-relevant returns as both being and happening are common words.

The question is, if there is a theory concerning these concepts - what is the gist? But as importantly, what are keywords that I could use to find useful results?

Comment: Heidegger used [a German word similar to "being"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dasein) prominently in his work as an existential philosopher...Don't suppose that's anywhere near the mark?

Comment: I don't know.. I appreciate it though, it helps! Blanco uses Symmetrical and Asymmetrical Being, and I believe I understand "Being" more than "Happening", but need to investigate.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you are referring to Erich Fromm's work on the "having" (not "happening") and "being" modes. [See here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_Have_or_to_Be%3F)

Comment: Good guess. Fromm is a likely name to hear in a psych class at a secondary school level.